# Emacs and AS3 auto-import

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, emacs, ide

Is there any way to auto-import as3 classes (internal/intrinsic Flash Player classes at least) using Emacs ?

Looked for [as3-mode](https://github.com/aemoncannon/as3-mode) and actionscript-mode but nothing working was found. as3-mode can 
import class if it is opened in buffer (but not *.mxml files)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with emacs unless there's some sort of plugin that knows about the playerglobals.swc.  Since the Flash Player classes are closed source, you won't be able to  use them properly.

Comment: yes, e.g. FlashDevelop can inspect swc files and look for class descriptions. That is the right way, there is another way - to get a ready presentation of classes in some xml files and then parse it. I have not much knowledge of elisp, so I can't implement it so far. I guess it is needed to use languages like java for parsing that swc, will elisp make it ?